# 'Pizza' object is not subscriptable Django

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Я попытался добавить атрибут возвращаемому объекту `QuerySet`a несколькими способами: `setattr(obj, 'field', 'value');` `obj.set(value)` и т.д. Но выдает ошибку

> 'Pizza' object is not subscriptable.

Я еще слабо разбираюсь, но можно ли добавить атрибут именно этому объекту? Или сделать что нибудь, что добавит атрибут?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

И `setattr` сработает и простое `obj.somefield = 'somevalue'`. Возникающая ошибка связана не с этим. Метод `get` возвращает не `QuerySet`, а экземпляр модели. Судя по ошибке где-то в другом участке кода, возможно в шаблоне, ожидается как раз `QuerySet`.